# Spring doesn't work with cucumber @ScenarioScope (IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'cucumber-glue')

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, cucumber

I have Cucumber tests. The stack for framework is **Cucumber 6 / Junit 4.13 / Spring 5.2 / Spring-boot-starter 2.3.**

For running Cucumber tests in parallel I use `@ScenarioScope` annotation to make **autowiring** instances to be recycled between scenarios.

Tests launch fine when I use `CucumberRunner`. E.g.:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports.html"},
features = {"classpath:features"},
glue = {"<some_glue_class>"})
public class CucumberRunnerTest {
}
```

But when I try run some Junit tests (**only**, without Cucumber) I get an error.

E.g. Context:

```
@Configuration
@Import({BeanConfigClass.class})
public class DefaultContext {
  // ...
}
```

Instance:

```
@ScenarioScope
@Component
public class Foo {
  // ...
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DefaultContext.class)
public class SomeTest {

  @Autowired
  private Foo foo;

  @Test
  public void fooTest(){
  //some test
  }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'cucumber-glue'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:357)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:675)
at Foo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1cf6c75d.replace(<generated>)
at test.SomeTest.fooTest(SomeTest.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

**Question:**
I understand that I need to use a kind of `CucumberRunner` to make Spring understand `cucumber-glue scope`. But how to implement it?
I would have the ability to create specific `bean`, but the class `CucumberScenarioScope` is **package-private** in `io.cucumber.spring`. So it doesn't work:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import static io.cucumber.spring.CucumberTestContext.SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE;
import static io.cucumber.spring.CucumberScenarioScope; //is not visible!

@Configuration
public class CustomScopeConfig {
@Bean
  public BeanFactoryPostProcessor beanFactoryPostProcessor(){
    return factory -> factory.registerScope(SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE, new CucumberScenarioScope());
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using Scenario scoped components in your regular JUnit tests?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Scenario scoped components are used in Cucumber tests. And it works well. But also I have some unit tests that are based on Junit and Spring only, and I want to get some of that components (classes) as autowired beans (from Spring bean factory). And in this case as that beans are annotated with `ScenarioScope` - Spring doesn't know about this annotation.

Comment: Just to clarify. In case of unit tests, annotation `ScenarioScope` - is not needed, but instances are annotated with it for running in cucumber tests.

Comment: How is a scenario scoped component useful in a unit test? You could autowire the components in the scenario scoped component directly into your unit test.

Comment: To avoid surprises you'd also have to stop/start the scenario scope around each unit test. Otherwise state would leak between tests (with regular components this is expected).

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje For example, I have class `Foo` with annotation `ScenarioScope`. Class is used both in cucumber test and in unit test. In first case everything is clear. In second - I want to autowire `Foo` as bean in unit test and now annotation `ScenarioScope` **is not needed**, there is no benefit here, even more, it hinders launching unit test as Spring doesn't know about it. But I can't get rid of this `ScenarioScope` annotation (as there is benefit for first case - cucumber test), and duplicating of classes (with `ScenarioScope` and without it) is not variant.

Comment: Unit tests are running without cucumber (only Spring and Junit). So there is exception: `IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'cucumber-glue'`.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to autowire foo into a unit test. Is `Foo` used as production code?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje `Foo` is used in automation-core of testing framework. It has some specific logic, so there are a kind of unit tests for some methods of `Foo` class, which verify this logic.

Comment: Ah. In that case rather then autowiring `Foo` you should create a new instance of `Foo` before each test (so `new Foo(...)`. You can still autowire the dependencies.

This also reflects what Cucumber does with the the `Foo` class.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje As far as I understood correctly - *the only one way* for using `Foo` in unit tests (without Cucumber) - is creating instance via `new Foo`. So the 'magic' of Spring Dependency Injection doesn't work here.

Comment: Yes. Scenario scoped beans can only be autowired during the execution of a scenario. So if you want to use them at anywhen else you have to construct them manually.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje thanks for clarifying!